# Logical operators and assignment in Perl

Tags: perl

**C code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int first = 10;
    int second = 20;
    int third = 30;

    int x = ((first == second) || third);

    printf ("%d", x);
}
```

`Output: 1`

**Perl code**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $first = 10;
my $second = 20;
my $third = 30;

my $x = (($first == $second) || $third);

print $x;
```

`Output: 30`

Why does Perl behave like this?

Comment: @ikegami  I'm unable to get why isn't the output `1`?

Comment: Perlop says `The ||, // and && operators return the last value evaluated (unlike C's || and &&, which return 0 or 1).`

Comment: @Dada Oh I see, thanks.

Comment: `my $x = 0 + !!(($first == $second) || $third);`

Comment: @SinanÜnür Completely forgot about using double negation.

Comment: It seems to me that `...?1:0` would be clearer than `0+!!(...)`.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, The OP didn't ask what it returns, but why it returns what it returns.

Comment: @ikegami It's not clear to me if he's asking about the reasoning behind it (why was Perl designed this way?) or just the mechanics (I expected 1, why am I getting 30?). I guess you think the former, which is maybe a more interesting angle; feel free to reopen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it can. C logical operators are unable to return something as useful as Perl's can because of C's type system.

Consider:

```
my $x = $arg || $default;
```

In C, you'd have to write the more complicated

```
int x = arg ? arg : default;
```